# Calling a HTTP Trigger Logic App (Post Call) with an Azure Function (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a Azure Logic App with a http trigger and would like to call this logic app with a Azure Function. I have tried to make a post call using the Requests Library. The code looks sth like this:

```
import requests

url='https://prod-56.westeurope.logic.azure.com:...'
requests.post(url)
```

When I try this code with VS Code it works. But somehow it doesn't work in Azure Functions. I have already changed CORS in the Azure function to allow all but it still didn't work. Any idea how i can call the logic app with a azure function in python?

Comment: it seems to me you're missing the payload.

Comment: Hi, I just want to activate the logic app. I have executed the code in Visual Studio Code and the logic app starts running. So the code should be fine. But when I use the code in Azure Functions, it doesn't work. Through Application Insight I can see that CORS is  addressed and I had to enable all (*) for CORS to be successful. But the Logic app doesn't start. If you try to start a logic app with a http trigger through an Azure Function, does it work?

Comment: sure! If you pass the expected parameter to trigger the Logic App, it will start running

Comment: So it doesn't work for you if you dont add a payload?

Comment: We need to install the **requests** module as you're using the requests module in your code. As stated in [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-I-import-modules-for-a-Python-Azure-Function), there is no direct way to obtain the module via packet manager. The `requirements.txt file` will automatically get generated if we implement in Vs code. However, you could use **kudu** console while working with Azure functions by setting up a **venv** and install the Python modules. I suggest you to execute the code directly in Visual Studio Code and deploy to azure using the **Publish** command.

Comment: Or if the above method using the Kudu console helps, I can provide you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results and i followed below process:

Firstly , I created http trigger in my local vs code as below and i added the code which i need to call logic app as below:

```
url='XX'
requests.post(url)
```

XX- url of logic app
[image]

My requirements.txt:

[image]

Then i deployed my function to azure and in portal requirements looks like below:

[image]

In code test of function:

[image]

[image]

Then in logic app( My logic app got triggered):

[image]