# Receiving messages from Azure Service Bus between a time period

Tags: java, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am wondering if its possible to receive messages from a service bus only during a certain time period.

I am subscribed to a topic (made my an external source) which will send data without any schedule in mind. However, from my side, I want to be able to only receive it within a certain time period. That is, from 08:00 to 24:00.

This is so that I avoid saving the message into the database.

Have tried looking for materials online but have not found exactly what I am looking for. Would really appreciate being led to source material that can help with this.

Comment: you could implement a durable function orchestration that just sleeps if outwith the required times. Within the required times it consumes messages from the topic using the SDK instead of a ServiceBusTrigger https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations?tabs=csharp
or a TimerTrigger that runs on a schedule between the required times and uses the SDK to consume messages from the topic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of doing this is to create Timer Trigger that runs on a schedule between the required times and then calling the Logic app from within the timer trigger as below:

Firstly, create a Timer Trigger function then from inside the function call a http URL( This is the trigger for logic app) as below:

[image]

By this way you can achieve your requirement. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74071284/calling-a-http-trigger-logic-app-post-call-with-an-azure-function-python/74121447#74121447)

Or else you can create a timer trigger and uses the SDK to read the messages from Queue or topic.